# Is it possible to reduce the equation of an tilted ellipse to the form $f(a,b)=A(x,y)g(a,b)+B(x,y)$?

Tags: polynomials, quadratics, conic-sections

First, I would like to introduce some background for the problem. I am currently dealing with a formula in crystallography which can be written as,
$$\frac{1}{d^2}=\frac{1}{\sin^2\beta}\left(\frac{h^2}{a^2}+\frac{l^2}{c^2}-\frac{2hl\cos\beta}{ac}\right).$$

Basically I have a bunch of $(h,l,d)$ experimental data and I want to use the data points I have to fit for parameters $a$ and $c$ ($\beta$ is known). I prefer linear fitting which is reliable to me and easy to work with.

I did some simple algebra to make the formula neat. Taking $\tilde{a}=\frac{1}{a}$, $\tilde{c}=\frac{1}{c}$, $\tilde{h}=\frac{hd}{\sin\beta}$ and $\tilde{l}=\frac{hl}{\sin\beta}$, and it is easy to get,
$$\tilde{a}^2\tilde{h}^2+\tilde{c}^2\tilde{l}^2-2\tilde{a}\tilde{c}\tilde{h}\tilde{l}\cos\beta=1.$$

I believe this is an equation describing an tilted ellipse curve in the $(\tilde{h},\tilde{l})$ plane. My **question** is, can I further separate the variables in the ellipse equation? Can it be rewritten in the form $f(\tilde{h},\tilde{l})=A(\tilde{a},\tilde{c})g(\tilde{h},\tilde{l})+B(\tilde{a},\tilde{c})$, where $f, g$ are both functions only of $\tilde{h},\tilde{l}$, and $A,B$ are both functions only of $\tilde{a},\tilde{c}$? I have tried hard but I can not make it. Could anyone please tell me if it is doable?

Comment: In short, I believe this problem is equivalent to the following problem: I have an equation for an tilted ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}-\frac{2\cos\beta}{ab}xy=1$. Is it possible to reduce it to the form $f(a,b)=A(x,y)g(a,b)+B(x,y)$?

Comment: You could map it to the unit circle with a further change of variables, which would let you completely separate them from $\tilde a$ and $\tilde c$.

Comment: @amd Thank you for reply. I have tried that way, see answer given by Will and my comments. The problem is the change of variables is dependent on $a,b$ which I have no knowledge on before doing the fitting. I can not do the transformation before finishing the fitting.

Comment: What if you treat it as an ellipse in the $\tilde a$-$\tilde b$ plane instead? You do know what $\tilde h$ and $\tilde l$ are.

Comment: @amd We can treat is as an ellipse on $\tilde{a}-\tilde{c}$ plane, then we end up with $\lambda_1 \tilde{a}'^2+\lambda_2 \tilde{c}'^2=1$, $\lambda_{1,2} $ are eigenvalues depending on $\tilde{h},\tilde{l}$, $\tilde{a}',\tilde{c}'$ are new variables. Again, the transformation is $\tilde{h},\tilde{l}$ dependent. If I do the linear fitting I can get the values of $\tilde{a}',\tilde{c}'$, but in the end I have to pick one data point to slove $a,c$ and abandon the rest points. It's doable but I doubt is not accurate.

Comment: @amd Thank you for you time helping me. Now I suspect the answer to my question is negative. I can't find a constant map (independent of $\tilde{h},\tilde{l}$) to do the linear fitting. I have to come up with other fitting methods.

Answer (score 1):

You have
$$ b^2 x^2 - 2ab \cos \beta \; \; \;  xy + a^2 y^2 = a^2 b^2 \; . $$

You want to orthogonally diagonalize the symmetric matrix
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
b^2 & - ab \cos \beta \\
-ab \cos \beta & a^2
\end{array}
\right)
$$
with trace $a^2 + b^2,$ determinant $a^2 b^2 \sin^2 \beta,$ eigenvalues
$$ \lambda = \frac{a^2 + b^2 \pm \sqrt{a^4 + (2 - 4 \sin^2 \beta) a^2 b^2 + b^4}}{2} $$
You then find the eigenvectors and make them unit length.

Comment: Hi Will, thank you for your reply! I understand we can write the left-hand side to be $(x\quad y)\left(\begin{matrix} b^2 & -ab\cos\beta \\-ab\cos\beta & a^2\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} x\\y \end{matrix}\right)$, then we can diagonalize the central matrix $M$ to be $M=Q\Lambda Q^{-1}$, with $\Lambda$=diag{$\lambda_1$,$\lambda_2$} where the diagonal elements are two eiginvalues of $M$, and $Q=(u_1,u_2)$ where $u_1,u_2$ are corresponding unit eigenvectors of $M$. $Q$ is also an othorgonal matrix with $Q^{-1}=Q^T$ due to the orthogonality of unit eigenvectors. (to be continued...)

Comment: (continued) then we can define $\left(\begin{matrix} \tilde{x}\\ \tilde{y} \end{matrix}\right)= Q^T\left(\begin{matrix} x\\ y \end{matrix}\right)$ and the equation finally reduced to $\lambda_1 \tilde{x}^2+\lambda_2 \tilde{y}^2=a^2b^2$. However now we have the form $f(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})=A(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})g(a,b)+B(\tilde{x},\tilde{y})$. $\tilde{x},\tilde{y}$ are related to $x,y$ by a linear transformation $Q^T$. The **dilemma** is that $Q^T$ is dependent on $a,b$, which are the parameters I don't know *a priori*. I cannot apply the transformation first and then do the linear fitting.